# What is the answer to the riddle in the necromancer training room?

Tags: clash-of-heroes

In *Might and Magic: Clash of Heroes* there is a riddle in the necromancer training room where a skeleton asks you to enter a two-digit number. The number he wants "matches" the number of spider legs, brass coins, and "broken time".

On the walls of the room are three murals, one of a spider with seven legs, one of three hourglasses of which one has fallen and broken, and one of five coins.

I have tried 13, the obvious answer, with no luck. I have also tried 15 assuming the two standing hourglasses still count as "broken time". Neither worked.

(I am playing on the DS but I imagine if the Xbox 360 / Playstation 3 versions follow the same campaign, the riddle has not changed.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did this one yesterday.. I remember being stuck at that part, but as far as I remember, it's the consecutive amount..

So 7 legs and two shiny coins plus one broken hourglass = 10

Comment: I had no idea the "shiny" part of the riddle was relevant. I'm playing the game on a 3DS and the "shine" has been muddy-filtered to something that stands out far less compared to my DSi.